# Is there a common outdoor cinema event/phenomena referenced in John Wick 2 and Jessica Jones season?

Tags: reference, jessica-jones, john-wick-chapter-2

John Wick 2 opens in the streets of New York, showing an old movie projected onto a wall. In Jessica Jones Season 2 episodes 1 and 7 set in New York, Jessica and Trish watch an old movie being projected onto a wall together from a rooftop.

Is that a reference to some anonymous New York-based movie screener, or some other phenomena or event that has occurred in New York? Is that something from the comics, implying they are in the same universe?

Comment: I'm thinking this might be a troupe that happens to also be common practice. Felicity and Ben also watch old films such as Gold Rush together with a projector on Shaun's rooftop in one episode of the Felicity TV series, which also takes place in New York City. But that show is 20 years old now.

Comment: Related, but not a dupe: [Why was there a clip of silent movie at the start of John Wick Chapter 2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74126/why-was-there-a-clip-of-silent-movie-at-the-start-of-john-wick-chapter-2)  Some interesting BTS for John Wick 2, but no reference to it being an actual event in New York IRL, so it's probably just a trope like @DarthLocke said.  Possibly a way of setting up scenes that would, pre-1990s, have otherwise been set at a drive-in theater?  That also explains Felicity, and it was in the 70s/80s that the popularity of drive-ins began dying off, IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Kind of.**

There is a *niche* practice of projecting films on buildings or rooftops in NY which partly inspired the opening scene of *John Wick 2*. JW2's director Chad Stahelski described the inspiration (and his choice of Buster Keaton) in [this interview to Slash Film](https://www.slashfilm.com/john-wick-chapter-2-director-chad-stahelski-interview/), saying:

> **We’re big fans of silent movies, or silent storytelling, or visual storytelling** as opposed to just exposition. So I had to reveal what we’ve already determined is kind of a mythological figure. Once again, let’s just stick to what we know, we’ll just do it with... When I say action I just don’t mean stunts, **I mean let’s just tell a story [visually]. It’s a wacky city** [...] and as a little nod to our established audience, **we want everybody to know that we’re making fun of ourselves. We’re gonna start with Buster Keaton.**
>
> ***We went to New York, and we saw all these kids from the NYC film school, and it was awesome, they’re just walking around with [t]his little projector on a little red wagon. It was really funny. With a little generator, they’re projecting all these silent movie images up on buildings and taking pictures, and that was part of their art project.*** Like, that’s f#@&ing genius. Yeah, I just talked to the kid, “I’m gonna steal your s#!@, man.” So I was like, **I’m gonna get the right to a Buster Keaton film, and I’m gonna project it on a wall, to let everybody know out there we’re making a fun action movie.**

But it's not just film students. [This 2009 New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/09/06/nyregion/06ritual.html) describes the practice through a couple in NY projecting rooftop movies for their friends (like Jessica Jones) and mentions a Brooklyn organization that does this *regularly*:

> What they found was nothing short of their own personal movie theater. The rooftop of their fourth-floor walk-up, besides affording majestic views of Manhattan, includes a white wall — a perfect surface for showing a movie. [...] Screening movies up on the roof is nothing new, of course. Rooftop Films, based in Brooklyn, has been doing it on summer weekends for years.

[Rooftop Films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooftop_Films) has been around since 1997, projecting independent shorts and well-known features against NY backdrops for large audiences. (They usually place *screens* on the intended buildings, though.)

Comment: Street projections aren't exclusive to NY, of course, [or to old movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_mapping).